# How to make my Rectangle move in Windows Phone 7 using Touch point?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm having a problem how do I move my simple Rectangle upward or downward using Touch input in Windows Phone 7. I manage to move the rectangle upward and do a hit test but how do I know if my touch input is going down?

I made a hitBox, here's my code.

```
        Rectangle hitbox = 
                  new Rectangle(32, 
                                GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds.Height / 2 - 64,
                                32,
                                128);

        foreach (TouchLocation location in TouchPanel.GetState())
        {
            hitbox = new Rectangle((int)blueBar.X, (int)blueBar.Y, 32, 128);
            if (hitbox.Contains((int)location.Position.X, (int)location.Position.Y))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("We’re hit!");
                blueBar.Y -= 10;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a rectangle to hit test a user's touch, why not try this approach:
http://codecube.net/2010/03/approximating-touch-points/

The idea is that you just activate the "closest" UI element to the touch point ... that way you don't have to worry about messy collision detection :-)

Aside from that, here's an article I wrote about using touch points to smoothly move a sprite on the screen:
http://codecube.net/2010/04/smooth-control-with-touch/